# Add Folder to TFVC with VS Code

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code, tfvc

I have an issue with vs code and source control TFVC. 
when I make any check-in to the server. any new folder is not uploaded right.
any idea?

[TFVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sndrl.png)

Comment: What is your expectation of behavior? Is `node_modules` in your `.tfignore` file? If it isn't, it should be; `node_modules` should not be source controlled but rather restored at build time via `npm install`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, I prefer **not** to let my project file know about the `node_modules` folder at all. And the projects load faster and I don't have to worry about the large commit messages in source control.

To achieve that we can [Customize which files are ignored by version control](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/tfvc/add-files-server?view=vsts#customize-which-files-are-ignored-by-version-control)

So, I agree with Daniel, in your scenario, if you mean you want to check in the `node_modules` folder and its sub-folders. Then you need to check if you have set the `ignore` rules in `.tfignore` file. If you set, just remove it.

---

**UPDATE:**

Based on OP's comment, as a workaround we can use Visual Studio to sync up the folder. (Check in the folder with VS, then sync to VS code)

Comment: Thanks ill try to customize files like that

Comment: I tried I could not do it with vscode . A workaround,  open the project with visual studio and create the new folder so I can sync up with. @Andy Li-MSFT